# Escrever na linha certa do arquivo e encontrar parâmetros presentes nele?

Tags: c#

Criei o arquivo:

```
FileInfo arq = new FileInfo("C:\\ProgramData\\dataMinGSMFans");

if (arq.Exists == false)
    File.Create("C:\\ProgramData\\dataMinGSMFans").Close();
```

Em um formulário vou ver se ele tem conteúdo e atribuir esse conteúdo a objetos do formulário (como nesse caso peguei a cor):

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\\ProgramData\\dataMinGSMFans");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("c1-"))
        cor1.BackColor = Color.FromName(line.Replace("c1-", "").Trim());
    else if (line.Contains("c2-"))
        cor2.BackColor = Color.FromName(line.Replace("c2-", "").Trim());
}
file.Close();
```

Para salvar no arquivo estou usando parâmetros diferentes, como uma key para identificar o que estou gravando, como `c1-` e `c2-`, cor1 e cor2:

```
var conteudo = string.Format("c1-{0}{1}", corPri.Color.Name, Environment.NewLine);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\ProgramData\\dataMinGSMFans", conteudo);

.
.
.

var conteudo = string.Format("c2-{0}{1}", corSec.Color.Name, Environment.NewLine);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\ProgramData\\dataMinGSMFans", conteudo);
```

**O problema é:** Está sempre gravando na primeira linha do arquivo, e apagando a outra que eu tinha escrito, quero saber como faço para escrever o conteúdo em uma linha vazia do arquivo sem apagar o arquivo todo, e caso já tenha uma linha do parâmetro `c1-` ou `c2-` (cor1 e cor2) ele substituir a linha existente alterendo apenas o valor depois do `-`

Comment: Eu não vou tentar responder porque não sei se entendi a pergunta e se entendi também não vou ficar pensando em toda a lógica disto (a concepção de como fazer isto também deve estar errada mas nem dá para saber sem ver toda a intenção do código) mas posso te ajudar dizendo que toda a concepção de como se trabalha com arquivos está errada. Dê uma pesquisada que tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto. Algumas ensinam deste jeito mesmo e está errado, outras, mostram corretamente como deve trabalhar com arquivos de uma forma geral.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma pesquisada á mais, os lugares em que pesquisei estavam assim, até mesmo aqui, em uma pergunta estava com uma resposta semelhante, mas vou continuar a procura.

Comment: É o que eu falei, muita gente aprendeu errado e ensina errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Método File.WriteAllText (String, String)

> Cria um novo arquivo, grava a cadeia de caracteres especificada no arquivo e, em seguida, fecha o arquivo. Se o arquivo de destino já existir, ele será substituído.

Então para continuar usando esse metodo, você precisa carregar e manipular antes de gravar todo o dado do seu arquivo em uma string, modificar como quiser e depois salvar ele.

```
//carregando os dados do arquivo
string dados = null;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(dados == null) dados = line;
    else dados += "\n"+line;
}

//modificar os parametros que vc quiser...
public static string modificarParametros(string dadosDoArquivo, string key, string valor)
{
    if(dadosDoArquivo == null) return null;
    string[] linhas = dados.Split(new char[]{'\n'});
    string saida = null;
    bool encontrado = false;
    foreach(string linha in linhas)
    {
        if(linha.Contains(key))
        {
            encontrado = true;
            linha = key + valor;
        }
        if(saida == null)
        {
            saida = linha;
        }
        else
        {
            saida += "\n"+linha;
        }
    }
    //se não exitir nenhum parametro com essa key ele adiciona um novo;
    if(!encontrado)
    {
        saida += "\n"+key+valor;
    }
    return saida;
}
```

Se pretende gravar objetos com varios parametros talvez seja interessante dar uma olhada em **serializable** que ele faz todo o trabalho pesado para você...

Comment: Era isso que eu tinha pensado em fazer, porém daria muito trabalho, daí fiz uma gambiarra, pois são muito poucas strings que preciso gravar, serão no máximo 5.. Então criei uma pasta e um arquivo para cada um, contendo o valor dela somente